# In the College Scorecard Data Directory--what is N=30

Tags: education, collegescorecard

In the directory file, for all the loan and debt numbers it says "suppressed for n=30". What is "n"?

Comment: Could you add the collegescorecard tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that n probably means number of students in cohort, but am not sure. Gainful Employment reporting I know is not publicly released when n<30 due to privacy reasons.

Here is some suppporting documentation: "[F]or elements that we expect to highlight on the consumer-facing College Scorecard, a separate version of the element is vailable that suppresses the data for schools with fewer than 30 students in the denominator to ensure the data are as representative as possible."

[Full College Scorecard Data Documentation](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/FullDataDocumentation.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, Evan. Concurring/confirming that 'n' refers to a number of students in a cohort for an individual institution